# Language Syntax Highlight - Comment Line Starts With * may or may not have following words

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, textmate, tmlanguage

I am creating a syntax highlight file for a language and I have everything mapped out and working with one exception.

I cannot come up with a regex that will match the following conditions for a specific line comment style.

If the first non white-space character is an asterisk (*) the line is considered a comment.

I have created many samples that work in regexr but it never captures in vscode.

For example, regexr is cool with this:
`^(?:\s*)\*+(?:.*)?\n`

So I convert it into the proper format for the tmlanguage.json file:
`^(?:\\s*)\\*+(?:.*)?\\n`

But it is not capturing properly, if the first character of the line is an *, it does not catch, but if the first character is a whitespace character followed by an * it does work.

I suck at formatting on stackoverflow, so  represents a chr(9) tab character.    is a space.

```
*******************************
  *****************************
<tab>*************************
* comment
  * comment
<tab>* comment

But it shouldn't work in these cases:
string *******************************
  string ***************************** string
<tab>string *************************
x *= 3
```

I am guessing that either the anchor ^ isn't working in my regex or I am escaping something incorrectly.

Any advice?

Please see sample image attached: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIAFl.png)

Comment: Are there any other rules in your grammar that are getting applied in the bad case? Does the [scope inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/08/syntax-highlighting-optimizations#_new-textmate-scope-inspector-widget) show anything interesting

Comment: @MattBierner, you hit the nail on the head.  I removed all other rules from the file and it worked properly which led me down the road to track down the issue.   I had a regex for a multiplier that was catching incorrectly on line 1.

Comment: Your example `^(?:\\s*)\\*+(?:.*)?\\n` works for me. If the issue is because of your other rules, please update the question or write an answer so as to conclude this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the regex engine you're using. I'm just going to give you some
general tips on how it should be done.

- First off, if you're reading a string with more than 1 newline in it,
  the anchor `^`, in an engines *default* state means ***Beginning of String*** (BOS)

What you want in this case is *Multi-Line-Mode*. This makes the anchor `^` match at the ***Beginning of Line*** (BO
L) as well as the BOS.

- Second, you don't need those non capture groups `(?:\s*)`  `(?:.*)`, they encapsulate single constructs.
- Third, it is redundant to make a group optional when its enclosed contents are optional `(?:.*)?`
- Fourth, you don't need the newline `\n` construct at the end, since it should not be highlighted anyway, and it might not be present on the last line of text.
  The latter will make it not match.

---

So, putting it all together, the modified regex would be `(?m)^\s*\*.*`

Explained

```
 (?m)     # Inline modifier: Multi-line mode
 ^        # Beginning of line
 \s*      # Optional many whitespace
 \*       # Required at least a single asterisk
 .*       # Optional rest of non-newline characters
```

Note that you could put a single capture group around the data
if you need to reference it in a replace `(?m)^(\s*\*.*)`

Also, the language you're using should have a way to specify *options* when compiling the regex. If the engine doesn't accept inline modifiers `(?m)` take it out and specify that option when compiling the regex.

Comment: Thank you sln, that is very helpful, but does not solve the issue I am having in the system I am working on.  Your answer attempt has been very helpful to me in general though.

Comment: VS Code's language highlighting engine (based on TextMate) does not support multiline regular expressions. I believe `^` should always match the start of the line

Comment: To you guys... I find it hard to believe there is no _Multiline_ option for the anchors `^$`. It doesn't matter anyway, there is a workaround, the hard way: `(?:^|(?<=\n))(\s*\*.*)` Or, if it doesn't support assertions, you'd have to actually consume the previous newline `(?:^|\n))(\s*\*.*)` and it becomes part of the match.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently VS Code's syntax highlighter is single-line. No matter how much i tried matching regeces that are over several lines, these never worked.

Second, if you're designing a language I suggest you not to use an arithmetic operator for comments.

Third, apparently you can match newlines in the `begin` and `end` attributes. You can try it there.